# Sqlalcemy - Bulk-insert with multiple cascade & back_populates relationships

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, insert, bulkinsert, cockroachdb

I have tried to optimize our insertions to the database, which is currently the bottleneck and slowing down our pipeline. I decided to first start speed up our data_generator used for testing, all the tables are empty at first. Thought it would be a easy place to start ..
they are then populated and used in various tests.
Currently, we do pretty much all insertions with *Session.add(entry)* or in some cases bulked entries with *add_all(entries)*, which does not improve the speed that much.

The goal was to do more insertions at once and have less time communicating back and forth with the database and I tried various bulk_insert methods (*bulk_save_objects,  bulk_insert_mappings* and ORM,CORE methods with *INSERT INTO, COPY, IMPORT ..* but I got nothing to work properly. Foreign key constraints, duplicated keys ... or tables not getting populated.

I will show an example of a Table that would previous be added with *add_all()* in a run_transaction.

```
class News(NewsBase):
__tablename__ = 'news'

news_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
url_visit_count = Column('url_visit_count', Integer, default=0)

# One to many
sab_news = relationship("sab_news", back_populates="news")
sent_news = relationship("SenNews", back_populates="news")
scope_news = relationship("ScopeNews", back_populates="news")
news_content = relationship("NewsContent", back_populates="news")

# One to one
other_news = relationship("other_news", uselist=False, back_populates="news")

# Many to many
companies = relationship('CompanyNews', back_populates='news', cascade="all, delete")
aggregating_news_sources = relationship("AggregatingNewsSource", secondary=NewsAggregatingNewsSource,
                                        back_populates="news")

def __init__(self, title, language, news_url, publish_time):
    self.news_id = uuid4()
    super().__init__(title, language, news_url, publish_time)
```

We have many tables built like this, some with more relations, and my conclusion now is that having many different relationships that back_populates and update each other does not allow for fast bulk_insertions, *Am I wrong?*

One of my current solution that was able to decrease our execution_time from 120s to 15s for a regular data_generator for testing is like this:

```
def write_news_to_db(news, news_types, news_sources, company_news,
                 ):
write_bulk_in_chunks(news_types)
write_bulk_in_chunks(news_sources)

def write_news(session):
    enable_batch_inserting(session)
    session.add_all(news)

def write_company_news(session):
    session.add_all(company_news)

engine = create_engine(
        get_connection_string("name"),
        echo = False,
        executemany_mode = "values")

run_transaction(create_session(engine=engine), lambda s: write_news(s))
run_transaction(create_session(), lambda s: write_company_news(s))
```

I used this library [sqlalchemy_batch_inserts
github](https://github.com/benchling/sqlalchemy_batch_inserts) together with Psycopg2 Fast Execution Helpers, set executemany_mode="values".
I did this by creating a new engine just for these insertions -  *It did work however this itself seems like a bad practice. It works with the same database*.

Anyway, this does seem to work, but it is still not the execution speed I want - especially when we are initially working with empty tables.

Ideally, I wouldn't want to do this hacky solution and avoid bulk_insertions since SQLAlchemy does not recommend using them - to avoid problems that I have faced.

**But how does one construct queries to properly do bulk_insertions in cases of complex Tables like these - should we re-design our tables or is it possible?**

Using Multi-row insertions within the run_transaction with ORM or CORE would be ideal, but I haven't been able to do it.

Any recommendations or help would be much appreciated!

TLDR; Bulk-insertion with multiple relationships, back_populates, cascade. How is it supposed to done?

Comment: Also being discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/8154).

Answer (score 0):

CockroachDB supports bulk insertions using multi-row insert for existing tables as well as IMPORT statements for new tables - https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/insert.html. Have you considered using these options directly?